# Return a map of all hidden hrefs on a page in watir

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

Is it possible to return a map of hidden links using watir?  I have been trying to find some useful documentation, but have been most unsuccessful.

I need it to be generic enough to return any link thats hidden on page regardless of class, id, etc

```
style=display: none;
```

This currently returns me all visible links

```
full_list = @driver.links.map{|a| a.href}
```

i'd like to do something like (my syntax is probably way off):

```
hidden_list = @driver.hiddens.map{:style, a => 'display: none;'}
```

Please, please let me know if there is a way!

Thanks!

Comment: could you try this code and see if it helps `@driver.hiddens(:style, 'display: none;').each { |h| puts h.value }`

Comment: @Singleton That didn't work.  My list is empty and my logger doesn't log anything. I only want to grab <a href.. values.  Excuse the question here, but what is 'h' referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find all the links that are not `visible?` and collect their href attributes:

For example, given the following html:

```
<a href="somewhere/visible">asdf</a>
<a style="display:none;" href="somewhere/invisible">asdf</a>
<a style="display:none;" href="somewhere/invisible2">asdf</a>
```

You can do:

```
hidden_list = @driver.links.find_all{ |a| !a.visible? }.collect(&:href)
#=> ["somewhere/invisible", "somewhere/invisible2"]
```